# How to separate redux api calls

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, axios

I have a "fetchComments" and "fetchCommentsById". Currently, When I console.log props.comments, I log all comments and comment 62, is there a way for me to separate the two?

```
const MainPage = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchComments();
    props.fetchCommentById(62);
  }, []);

  console.log("all comments: ", props.comments);

  return (
    <>
      <div>MainPage</div>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { comments: state.comments };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchComments, fetchCommentById })(
  MainPage
);
```

Here is my comments reducer.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_COMMENTS:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case FETCH_COMMENT_BY_ID:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reducer, instead of storing just the comments in an array, store an object which contains both full comments and the commentById.

**Mainpage component:**

```js
const MainPage = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchComments();
    props.fetchCommentById(62);
  }, []);

  console.log("all comments: ", props.comments);
  console.log("comment by id: ", props.commentById);

  return (
    <>
      <div>MainPage</div>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { 
    commentById: state.comments.commentById,
    comments: state.comments.comments
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchComments, fetchCommentById })(
  MainPage
);
```

**Change your reducer like this:**

```js
const initialState = {
  comments: [],
  commentById: ''
}
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_COMMENTS:
      return {...state, comments: action.payload}; // assuming you are returning an array from the server
    case FETCH_COMMENT_BY_ID:
      return {...state, commentById: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I had to change commentById to equal to empty string in initial state because it was throwing an error when I render it to the DOM.

Comment: great... i have updated the answer with `empty string` ... you can please consider to accept the answer if it has helped .. thanks.